# How to use Spring SimpleThreadScope?

Tags: java, spring

Spring 3.0 defines a [SimpleThreadScope](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/SimpleThreadScope.html). Looking at all known implementing classes of the [Scope interface](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/Scope.html), I see: AbstractRequestAttributesScope, PortletContextScope, RequestScope, ServletContextScope, SessionScope, SimpleThreadScope.

The first observation is that I don't see a PrototypeScope, and don't understand why.

My question, though, is how to use SimpleThreadScope, since RequestScope becomes "request" in XML or annotation, so I tried to use "simplethread" and "simpleThread", but they don't work.

I get the following message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for scope 'simpleThread'
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
```

Does it mean that SimpleThreadScope should be used only programmatically, not through XML or annotations? And how to use it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SimpleThreadScope` is not registered by default, so that you need to register it manually in order to use it, see [3.5.5.2 Using a custom scope](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-custom-using).

`singleton` and `prototype` scopes don't have their `Scope` classes since they are hardcoded into bean factory.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to use `SimpleThreadScope` in Spring Boot.

Go to the Application class where your project starts when executed.

Then will need to import the following:

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomScopeConfigurer;
import org.springframework.context.support.SimpleThreadScope;
```

Create a static method that returns an object of type CustomScopeConfigurer and apply the `@Bean` annotation to it:

```java
@Bean
public static CustomScopeConfigurer yourCustomScopeConfigurer() {}
```

This will indicate that this method will produce a bean to be managed by the Spring container.

Then, create a new `CustomScopeConfigurer` which you will setup later.

```java
@Bean
public static CustomScopeConfigurer yourCustomScopeConfigurer() {
  final CustomScopeConfigurer newConfigurer = new CustomScopeConfigurer();
  return newConfigurer;
}
```

We use the keyword `final` here to create a constant object which you can setup but you can't modify. In other words, the reference variable cannot be re-bound to another object. The internal state of the object pointed by this reference variable can be changed.

Next, we need to register all of the supplied scopes, here is where we use the `SimpleThreadScope` via a HashMap:

```java
@Bean
public static CustomScopeConfigurer yourCustomScopeConfigurer() {
  final CustomScopeConfigurer newConfigurer = new CustomScopeConfigurer();
  Map<String, Object> newScopes = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  newScopes.put("thread", new SimpleThreadScope());
  newConfigurer.setScopes(newScopes);
  return newConfigurer;
}
```

**Optional**

You might want to use the `@EnableAsync` annotation which enables Spring's asynchronous method execution capability:

```java
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
...
@EnableAsync
public class YourProjectApplication{
...
}
```

*Note: the three dots means code between those lines.*